# Firebase Reatime Database datasnapshot.hasChild

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In Firebase Realtime Database there have thousands of child nodes (users). If I use `snapshot.hasChild(user1)`
is it an efficient way (I mean lightweight operation), or is there have another way?

I'm worried is the function download all the child nodes.

Answer (score 1):

A `DataSnapshot` is a snapshot of all the data at a certain location, or matching a certain query. If you download thousands of nodes to check whether one of then exists, you're definitely wasting bandwidth.

Did you consider only loading the data for `child(user1)` to begin with?

Say that you have this now:

```
myReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot.hasChild(user1)) {
            ...
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Firebase:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
    }
};
```

You could get the same result by only loading the `user1` child node with:

```
myReference.child(user1).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
          //  only load the one node we care about
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) { //  check if the snapshot exists
            ...
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Firebase:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
    }
};
```